# MS-DOS commands doesn't work (COPY and ERASE)

Tags: copy, dos, erase

I have done this .bat file to copy some maps and textures from my USB drive to the valve installation path, but it doesn't work, why?

```
@echo on
COPY \CS-Fix\Maps\*.* %PROGRAMFILES%\Valve\Half-Life\cstrike\maps
COPY \CS-Fix\Textures\*.* %PROGRAMFILES%\Valve\Half-Life\cstrike\
ERASE %PROGRAMFILES%\Valve\Half-Life\cstrike\maps\de_shipment.bsp
pause
```

What is wrong?

Comment: @Cthulhu I don't understand you. What directory are you talking about? Valve install path or USB path?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Does it not copy the files? Does it not erase them? (`Erase` could be `del` instead, which is shorter, BTW.) Do you get an error message? What drive are you on when you run it? Do you have a `\CS-Fix` folder on the root of that drive?

Comment: do the folders exist already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%PROGRAMFILES%` indicates that you're using Windows, not MS-DOS.

MS-DOS was Microsoft's variant of DOS, an operating system that preceded Windows.

Anyway, two main problems are apparent to my tired eyes:

- Paths that possibly have spaces and are not quoted.
- Probably no write access to the relevant folders.

To fix the first problem, quote paths.

The second problem is only a problem in Windows Vista and later.

You can probably fix that by running the batch file from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: It worked, the environment variable was screwing up my script.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the batch file is sitting on and being run from your thumb drive.

Do the paths need to be quoted?

```
@echo on
COPY "\CS-Fix\Maps\*.*" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Valve\Half-Life\cstrike\maps"
COPY "\CS-Fix\Textures\*.*" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Valve\Half-Life\cstrike\"
ERASE "%PROGRAMFILES%\Valve\Half-Life\cstrike\maps\de_shipment.bsp"
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

You might need to quote things. %PROGRAMFILES% probably expands out to C:\Program Files. Try something like this:

```
@echo on
COPY "\CS-Fix\Maps\*.*" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Valve\Half-Life\cstrike\maps"
COPY "\CS-Fix\Textures\*.*" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Valve\Half-Life\cstrike\"
ERASE "%PROGRAMFILES%\Valve\Half-Life\cstrike\maps\de_shipment.bsp"
pause
```